C# WPF moving the "map" object and separately the internal movement of objects(item) inside it
There is a ListView that is itself an "interactive map" that I want to move and zoom in on. And on this "map" there are elements (ListViewItem) that I also want to move relative to this map. But the problem is that I use one code (someone else's) to move the map itself, and I use another (someone else's) code to move objects inside the map, but they don't get along together) how do I set it up so that they work together? Maybe it needs to be processed - what is the selected ListViewItem or the ListView itself?
The code for moving the Listview is "maps":
public class ZoomBorder : Border
    {
        private UIElement child = null;
        private Point origin;
        private Point start;

        private TranslateTransform GetTranslateTransform(UIElement element)
        {
            return (TranslateTransform)((TransformGroup)element.RenderTransform)
              .Children.First(tr => tr is TranslateTransform);
        }

        private ScaleTransform GetScaleTransform(UIElement element)
        {
            return (ScaleTransform)((TransformGroup)element.RenderTransform)
              .Children.First(tr => tr is ScaleTransform);
        }

        public override UIElement Child
        {
            get { return base.Child; }
            set
            {
                if (value != null && value != this.Child)
                    this.Initialize(value);
                base.Child = value;
            }
        }

        public void Initialize(UIElement element)
        {
            this.child = element;
            if (child != null)
            {
                TransformGroup group = new TransformGroup();
                ScaleTransform st = new ScaleTransform();
                group.Children.Add(st);
                TranslateTransform tt = new TranslateTransform();
                group.Children.Add(tt);
                child.RenderTransform = group;
                child.RenderTransformOrigin = new Point(0.0, 0.0);
                this.MouseWheel += child_MouseWheel;
                this.MouseLeftButtonDown += child_MouseLeftButtonDown;
                this.MouseLeftButtonUp += child_MouseLeftButtonUp;
                this.MouseMove += child_MouseMove;
                this.PreviewMouseRightButtonDown += new MouseButtonEventHandler(
                  child_PreviewMouseRightButtonDown);
            }
        }

        public void Reset()
        {
            if (child != null)
            {
                // reset zoom
                var st = GetScaleTransform(child);
                st.ScaleX = 1.0;
                st.ScaleY = 1.0;

                // reset pan
                var tt = GetTranslateTransform(child);
                tt.X = 0.0;
                tt.Y = 0.0;
            }
        }

        #region Child Events

        private void child_MouseWheel(object sender, MouseWheelEventArgs e)
        {
            if (child != null)
            {
                var st = GetScaleTransform(child);
                var tt = GetTranslateTransform(child);

                double zoom = e.Delta > 0 ? .2 : -.2;
                if (!(e.Delta > 0) && (st.ScaleX < .4 || st.ScaleY < .4))
                    return;

                Point relative = e.GetPosition(child);
                double absoluteX;
                double absoluteY;

                absoluteX = relative.X * st.ScaleX + tt.X;
                absoluteY = relative.Y * st.ScaleY + tt.Y;

                st.ScaleX += zoom;
                st.ScaleY += zoom;

                tt.X = absoluteX - relative.X * st.ScaleX;
                tt.Y = absoluteY - relative.Y * st.ScaleY;
            }
        }

        private void child_MouseLeftButtonDown(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
        {
            if (child != null)
            {
                var tt = GetTranslateTransform(child);
                start = e.GetPosition(this);
                origin = new Point(tt.X, tt.Y);
                this.Cursor = Cursors.Hand;
                child.CaptureMouse();
            }
        }

        private void child_MouseLeftButtonUp(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
        {
            if (child != null)
            {
                child.ReleaseMouseCapture();
                this.Cursor = Cursors.Arrow;
            }
        }

        void child_PreviewMouseRightButtonDown(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
        {
            this.Reset();
        }

        private void child_MouseMove(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
        {
            if (child != null)
            {
                if (child.IsMouseCaptured)
                {
                    var tt = GetTranslateTransform(child);
                    Vector v = start - e.GetPosition(this);
                    tt.X = origin.X - v.X;
                    tt.Y = origin.Y - v.Y;
                }
            }
        }

        #endregion
    }

The code for moving an item to a ListView:
int countZ = 0;
        bool _canMove = false;
        Point _offsetPoint = new Point(0, 0);

        private static T FindParent<T>(DependencyObject dependencyObject) where T : DependencyObject
        {
            var parent = VisualTreeHelper.GetParent(dependencyObject);

            if (parent == null) return null;

            var parentT = parent as T;
            return parentT ?? FindParent<T>(parent);
        }

        private void FF_MouseDown(object sender, System.Windows.Input.MouseButtonEventArgs e)
        {
            _canMove = true;
            countZ++;

            //FrameworkElement ffElement = (FrameworkElement)sender;
            FrameworkElement ffElement = FindParent<ListViewItem>((FrameworkElement)sender);
            Grid.SetZIndex(ffElement, countZ);

            Point posCursor = e.MouseDevice.GetPosition(this);
            /*_offsetPoint = 
               new Point(posCursor.X - ffElement.Margin.Left, posCursor.Y - ffElement.Margin.Top);
            */
            _offsetPoint = new Point(
                    posCursor.X - Canvas.GetLeft(ffElement),
                    posCursor.Y - Canvas.GetTop(ffElement)
            );


            e.MouseDevice.Capture(ffElement);
        }

        private void FF_MouseMove(object sender, System.Windows.Input.MouseEventArgs e)
        {
            if (_canMove == true)
            {
                FrameworkElement ffElement = FindParent<ListViewItem>((FrameworkElement)sender);
                Point p = e.MouseDevice.GetPosition(this);
                Canvas.SetLeft(ffElement, p.X - _offsetPoint.X);
                Canvas.SetTop(ffElement, p.Y - _offsetPoint.Y);
            }
        }

        private void FF_MouseUp(object sender, System.Windows.Input.MouseButtonEventArgs e)
        {
            _canMove = false;
            e.MouseDevice.Capture(null);
        }

The ListView in XAML looks like this:
<Grid>
            <local:ZoomBorder x:Name="border" ClipToBounds="True" Background="Gray">
                <ListView x:Name="ItemsCollection" Foreground="{x:Null}" Margin="0,218,0,0" IsTextSearchEnabled="False" SelectionChanged="ItemsCollection_SelectionChanged" IsHitTestVisible="True" >
                    <ListView.Background>
                        <ImageBrush ImageSource="/1678120848_bogatyr-club-p-kiberpank-laboratoriya-foni-pinterest-55.png"/>
                    </ListView.Background>
                    <ListView.ItemsPanel>
                        <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                            <Canvas IsItemsHost="True"/>
                        </ItemsPanelTemplate>
                    </ListView.ItemsPanel>
                    <ItemsControl.ItemContainerStyle>
                        <Style TargetType="{x:Type ListViewItem}">
                            <Setter Property="Canvas.Left" Value="{Binding X}" />
                            <Setter Property="Canvas.Top" Value="{Binding Y}" />
                        </Style>
                    </ItemsControl.ItemContainerStyle>
                    <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <Canvas Width="50" Height="50" Background="#FFD82B2B" MouseDown="FF_MouseDown" MouseMove="FF_MouseMove" MouseUp="FF_MouseUp"/>
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                </ListView>
            </local:ZoomBorder>
        </Grid>


Where you got the "someone else's" code? He or she might have kindly left useful information.
